# Retirar painel lateral do Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Existe alguma maneira de retirar/remover esta parte do Visual Studio Code?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for o *map mode* nativo, presente nas versões novas do VSCode, mude isto:

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Link para o manual:

> https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap

Se for alguma versão mais velha, precisa desinstalar a extensão que habilita o *map mode*.